# Python: too many joins()?

Tags: python, join, filepath

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I'm using `str.join()` and `os.path.join()` at different points in the script, is that the cause?

Using os.path.join:

```
from os.path import getsize, dirname, join

class Wav:
    src_path = "No path"
    dest_path = destination
    old_name = "name.wav"
    new_name = ""

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.src_path = path
        self.old_name = os.path.split(path)
        self.new_name = self.old_name
        self.dest_path = join(destination, self.new_name) # error here
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "call.py", line 132, in <module>  
    temp = Wav(temp_path)  
  File "call.py", line 32, in __init__  
    self.dest_path = join(destination, self.new_name)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join  
    if b.startswith('/'):  
 AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Is this a conflict with `str.join()` or am I not importing `os.path` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.dest_path = join(destination, self.new_name) # error here
```

`self.new_name` is not a string, it's a tuple, so you can't use it as the second argument to `join`. Perhaps you meant to join `destination` with just the last element of `self.new_name`?

```
self.dest_path = join(destination, self.new_name[1])
```

Comment: Of course I forgot `os.path.split()` returns a tuple!  Thank you, I chaged the line above so that old name will be a string rather than a tuple, fixing the things constructed with self.old_name.

Comment: and don't forget about `import pdb` and `pdb.set_trace()` wherever necessary to inspect what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`self.new_name` is a tuple, not a string in your code, and `os.path.join` takes a list of strings, not a string and a list.  You could do it with

```
self.dest_path = join(destination, *self.new_name)
```

to expand `self.new_name` as parameters to `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if destination and self.new_name are lists or.       tuples

Tuples (they look so:

```
mytup = ('hey','folk')
```

) have no attribute startswith. You have to use strings. To check this just print the variables out in your program.

2. I don't think join replaces each other but you should try it.

   import os.path

Write this under your first import line. Then replace

join(...,...)

with

os.path.join(...,...)

if you want to use the os.path module.